# Python matplotlib Colormap - normalizing a range of many close values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a Pandas Series of 20 values that I'm trying to chart with a custom color map, but it's returning the same color for every single value though they are unique. I've used this same code with a wider range and it works, it seems the numbers being so close is the issue.

```
#my array
print(combined.values)
print(type(combined.values))

[4.58019608 4.4845098  4.4818     4.4288     4.4166     4.40807692
 4.3688     4.359      4.3446     4.3318     3.6424     3.6306
 3.6248     3.6194     3.617      3.6152     3.5628     3.4948
 3.4424     3.3692    ]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ['white', 'black'])
#try to pass values to cmap
print(cmap(combined.values))
[[0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

How can I normalize these values for the colormap? Ideally the minimum would be at the start and the max would be at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that matplotlib colormaps require the passed value to be between 0 and 1. Normalizing your data array to fall between 0 and 1 inclusive (i.e., "MinMaxScaling" it) appears to produce (r, g, b, a) values that represent a useful grayscale gradient.

```
c = combined.values.copy()
c = (c - c.min()) / (c.max() - c.min())

cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ['white', 'black'])
print(cmap(c))

[[0.         0.         0.         1.        ]
 [0.07843137 0.07843137 0.07843137 1.        ]
 [0.07843137 0.07843137 0.07843137 1.        ]
 [0.1254902  0.1254902  0.1254902  1.        ]
 [0.13333333 0.13333333 0.13333333 1.        ]
 [0.14117647 0.14117647 0.14117647 1.        ]
 [0.17254902 0.17254902 0.17254902 1.        ]
 [0.18039216 0.18039216 0.18039216 1.        ]
 [0.19215686 0.19215686 0.19215686 1.        ]
 [0.20392157 0.20392157 0.20392157 1.        ]
 [0.77647059 0.77647059 0.77647059 1.        ]
 [0.78431373 0.78431373 0.78431373 1.        ]
 [0.78823529 0.78823529 0.78823529 1.        ]
 [0.79607843 0.79607843 0.79607843 1.        ]
 [0.79607843 0.79607843 0.79607843 1.        ]
 [0.79607843 0.79607843 0.79607843 1.        ]
 [0.84313725 0.84313725 0.84313725 1.        ]
 [0.89803922 0.89803922 0.89803922 1.        ]
 [0.94117647 0.94117647 0.94117647 1.        ]
 [1.         1.         1.         1.        ]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is in the right direction but this method causes a really sharp cut-off at the halfway point - you can see the jump in the middle from 0.2 to 0.7.

I found that `c = (c / c.max())` works better to minimize that jump but it only leaves me with a range of 1 to .73. I'm wondering if there's still a better way to normalize these. Built in to the colormap or plotting function would be fantastic...

Comment: @MajorMajor, the input data has a jump (from values roughly at and above ~4.3 down to ~3.6), so I'd say the colormap is doing its job :P

Comment: lol whoops, completely forgot that I was taking from both ends of my data set for this... I'm braindead tonight, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @MajorMajor, happens to all of us - you're welcome and happy coding!

Comment: Note that this is usually written like `norm = plt.Normalize(c.min(), c.max()); cmap(norm(values))`